# How do I create a Javascript method for any variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure the question title is right.
Let's say I have:

```
var myArray=[12, 1, 25];
```

I want to write a function such as the following "multiply" function so that I can:

```
var newArray = myArray.multiply(7)
```

and the result would be:

```
newArray=[12*7, 1*7, 25*7]
```

But I'm not referring only to an array. Initial variable could be a string to do something with.

Comment: Chaining is where calling a function returns a function. You're asking about adding a method to arrays.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `map`

Comment: I know I could do it by writing a function like function multiply(arr){process each element of arr and return result } but that's not how I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a `multiply` function to the `prototype` of Array.

See the code below.

```js
var myArray=[12, 1, 25];

Array.prototype.multiply = function(arg) {
  return this.map(item => item*arg);
}

var newArr = myArray.multiply(7);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This a great answer. It is what I was looking for. Array.prototype and String.prototype.